# Помогите найти ошибку в коде Python

Tags: python

Есть список запросов в строке queries. Задача написать скрипт, который выводит на экран строчку queries, в которой оставлены только те запросы, которые содержат слова из запроса words. Есть скрипт, но выдает ошибку TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

```
queries = "смотреть сериалы онлайн,новости спорта,афиша кино,курс доллара,сериалы этим летом,курс по питону,сериалы про спорт"
words = ['сериалы', 'курс']

queries_list = queries.split()
new_list = []
for query in queries_list:
    for words[0] in query or words[1] in query:
        new_list.append(queries_list)
result = ','.join(new_list)
print(result)
```

Comment: `new_list.append(queries_list)` - тут вы добавляете в список весь исходный список запросов, а нужно только текущий запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что деление должно быть не по пробелам, а по запятой.
Про `append` элемента, а не целого списка уже сказали.
Вместо `for words` подразумевалось `if`

```
queries_list = queries.split(sep = ",")
new_list = []
for query in queries_list:
    if words[0] in query or words[1] in query:
        new_list.append(query)
result = ",".join(new_list)
print(result)

[Dbg]>>> смотреть сериалы онлайн,курс доллара,сериалы этим летом,курс по питону,сериалы про спорт
```